# textSize in Radio Buttons doesn't follow defined style

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout there are two styles defined for two different elements: a headline (upper) and radio buttons. They both should have textSize of 30sp in `sw600dp` and wider layouts; this is how it looks in their styles:
`<item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>`.

In the meantime, they look like:

[image]

How can I make the radio button text become bigger?

EDIT: adding styles & code of both elements.

1a. Headline code:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/q1_question"
                style="@style/headlineTextView"/>
```

1b. Headline style:

-- parent:

```
<style name="textViewParent">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkest_gray</item>
</style>
```

-- child:

```
<style name="headlineTextView" parent="textViewParent">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkest_gray</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">40dp</item>
</style>
```

2a. Radio Button code:

```
<RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/qf2e_radio_ans0"
                android:text="@string/desc_flag_0"
                style="@style/quizRadioButton" />
```

2b. Radio Button style:

-- no-parent:

```
<style name="quizRadioButton">
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkest_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">20dp</item>
</style>
```

The buttons are grouped under RadioGroup.

Comment: Please include those styles and layout code in your question. I guess there's a problem with the way you define textSize value for different screen sizes.

Comment: Can you provide code of your layout file? it will be helpful to suggest you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to make your standard widget's styles inherit the standard styles. For example, your radio button style should look like:

```
<style name="quizRadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
```

Once you do that, the `textSize` attribute will work.

Comment: I added this: `<style name="quizRadioButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">`. Didn't work with that. May it be AppCompat's fault?

Comment: That's the way I use it in my applications. When you say it doesn't work - do you mean the text size stays the same no matter what, or the size is different than what you expect?

Comment: Nothing changes actually.

Comment: I tried to replace the path to parent style by the one given by you, but Android Studio doesn't accept any children of `parent="@android:style/Widget"`.

Comment: Is it possible that you have defined `<style name="quizRadioButton">` in multiple styles.xml files? (residing in multiple values-vXX folders) so that your changes in one file are ignored because the style is picked up from a different file?

Comment: Yes, I do have this style defined separately for different layouts. Will try to add parent to each one.

Comment: not only the parent, but the `<item name="android:textSize">XXsp</item>` to the ones you are trying out.

Comment: `<item name="android:textSize">` was defined for each anyway. However, changing (adding the `parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton"` part didn't result in anything. Maybe replacing the size with `@dimens/rbTextSize` will help.

Comment: Dealing with `@dimen` didn't help either.